# reading and storing data to a 2D Array from a CSV file on a windows form application

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

I can't seem to get my csv file to store data into a 2D Array.

This what my code looks like so far:

```
try
{
    string nrValues;
    fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //    open for reading
    // the file has opened; can read it now
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        parts = line.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.Length; i++)
        {
            textiles[nrValues, i] = parts[i];
        }

        nrValues++;
    }
```

This is what my csv file looks like:

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0QMP.jpg)

Comment: You also have defined `nrValues` as a string instead of an int and this should result in a compile error, at least for nrValues++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to read your data with the code snippet below. I have changed `nrValues` to be an integer and I am using `parts.Length` instead of `sizes.Length` as you didn't include a definition for `sizes`. However, please have a look at the improved version at the end of this answer. Using LINQ  you can implement the same code in two lines.

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int nrValues=0;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //    open for reading
            // the file has opened; can read it now
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

            string[,] textiles = new string[6, 4];

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] parts = line.Split(',');

                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    textiles[nrValues, i] = parts[i];
                }
                nrValues++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, much neater and shorter, you can write the same code using LINQ if you are happy for the result to be a jagged array instead of a 2D array:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var textiles = lines.Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Comment: Since one of the problems was actually with variable types, would it not be more helpful to declare the types in your snippet instead of using `var`?

Comment: @Ciara, I have updated the post to define the types explicitly. Using var is a bit of  professional laziness:-) I  agree that in this case it is better to define the types explicitly.